# How to plot a subset of all the vertices of a graph that are linked to same vertex using igraph in R?

Tags: r, plot, subset, igraph

I'd like to find and plot the subset of all the vertices that are connected to vertex #18 in network 'g', including not only adjacent nodes (neighbors) but also those that have any possible path to it

```
g <- (make_full_graph(10) + make_full_graph(10))
plot(g) #plots 2 separate networks:
```

[image: 2 separate networks]

After finding all the vertices that have a path to vertex #18, the resulting sub-graph should look like this:

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not to leave this question unanswered ...

You want the subgraph consisting of the connected component that contains node 18. The only thing that is slightly tricky is that `induced_subgraph` renumbers the nodes, so if you want to preserve the original numbering, you need to explicitly set the labels on the subgraph.

```
## Your sample graph
g <- (make_full_graph(10) + make_full_graph(10))
plot(g)

## Get Connected component for node 18
Comp = components(g)
Comp18 = which(Comp$membership == Comp$membership[18])

## Extract subgraph and name nodes based on old numbering
g2 = induced_subgraph(g, Comp18)
g2 = set_vertex_attr(g2, "label", value = Comp18 )
plot(g2)
```

[image: Subgraph]